# Регулярное выражение удаляет неправильные данные

Tags: php

```
$line2 = "<script asynx src=\"//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js\"></script>";
$line2 = preg_replace("/[^https:]\/\/.*/u","",$line2);

print $line2;
```

Результат: `<script async src=`

Хотя должно быть:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Забыли добавить результат)

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь своим регулярным выражением сделать?

Comment: Не понятно, что нужно и что пытаетесь сделать, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы было понятно, что нужно сделать.